# Javascript menu on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with an image and a hidden navbar inside it. When i click on the div i want it to show the hidden menu but for some reason it doesnt work. Ideally, i would like the navbar to slide out from the right but at the moment just want it to appear wehn I click the button.

The menu is hidden using display: none; and i tried to get it to reapper using the javascript .style but for some reason it will not work.

**My Code**

```js
var menu = document.querySelectorAll(".navigation-mobile");

function onMenuClick() {
  menu.style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
.navigation-mobile {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #2a3b4d;
  height: 100%;
  top: -20px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navigation-mobile a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-elements-mobile {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

a .nav-elements-mobile {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 300px;
}

a .nav-elements-mobile:hover {
  background-color: #243342;
}

.mobile-nav-button {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  right: 25px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
}

#menu-icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.mobile-nav-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  .navigation {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-nav-button {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-nav-button" onclick="onMenuClick();">
  <img id="menu-icon" src="Images/Home Page/MenuButton.png" />
  <ul class="navigation-mobile">
    <a href="">
      <li class="nav-elements-mobile">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="nav-elements-mobile">Find a Team</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="nav-elements-mobile">Contact Us</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="nav-elements-mobile">Gallery</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="nav-elements-mobile">Forms</li>
    </a>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Because with `document.querySelectorAll` you are getting `All` elements with that specific class. Either iterate through all of them in your function or select a specific one you want to change the style of.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns you node list of all the matching elements. And there is no any property of `style` on the node list. What you need is `document.querySelector` which will return you just the first matching node and you can apply style properties to hide, show or whatever.

Or you can use `document.querySelectorAll(`selector`)[0]` to get the first selector if you want

ps. If you want to add the sliding effect. It would be easy with `jquery`.  Just replace the `menue.style.display=block` with `$(".navigation-mobile").slideDown()` and that should give you sliding affect

```js
var menu = document.querySelector(".navigation-mobile");

function onMenuClick() {
  menu.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.navigation-mobile {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #2a3b4d;
  height: 300px;
  top: -20px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navigation-mobile a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-elements-mobile {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

a .nav-elements-mobile {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 300px;
}

a .nav-elements-mobile:hover {
  background-color: #243342;
}

.mobile-nav-button {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  right: 25px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
}

#menu-icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.mobile-nav-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  .navigation {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-nav-button {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-nav-button" onclick="onMenuClick();">
  <img id="menu-icon" src="Images/Home Page/MenuButton.png" />
  <ul class="navigation-mobile">
    <a href="">
      <li class="nav-elements-mobile">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="nav-elements-mobile">Find a Team</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="nav-elements-mobile">Contact Us</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="nav-elements-mobile">Gallery</li>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <li class="nav-elements-mobile">Forms</li>
    </a>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed it and removed the All but it still isnt working

Comment: that may be an issue with the height of `.navigation-mobile"`. Change height to `300px` for example

Comment: can't you verify with this above snipped I added ?

Comment: It works on the snippet but not in my code. Not too sure why